# create variable width buffer for spatiallinesdataframe

Tags: r, spatial

I'd like to create a variable width buffer for a spatiallinesdataframe. I have a road shapefile with a width attribute that I'd like to base my road buffer off of. For example, if I have a 5 m wide section of road, I'd like my buffer to be 2.5 m on each side. If I have a 10 m wide section of road, I'd like my buffer to be 5 m on each side, etc.

Currently, I know of two buffering functions: rgeos::gBuffer and raster::buffer, but both only create a buffer based on a single value (that I know of). Does anyone know of a function that I could do this with?

I'd like to do something like this:

rdWidth <- roads.width$WIDTH/2

roads.buff <- buffer_function(roads.width, width = rdWidth)

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the different road widths

Example data:

```
library(raster)
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60))
cds2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55))
cds3 <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45))   
lns <- spLines(cds1, cds2, cds3, attr=data.frame(width=2*(1:3)))
```

Solution:

```
w <- unique(lns$width)
b <- list()
for (i in 1:length(w)) {
    x <- lns[lns$width==w[i], ]
    b[[i]] <- buffer(x, w[i])
} 
bb <- do.call(bind, b)

plot(bb)
```